# show/hide components

Tags: javascript, angular.js

The following code is used to show/hide components in an AngularJS app:

```
var vm = this;

var hideComponents = function()
{
   vm.showRegions = false;
   vm.showAccounts = false;
   vm.showOrders = false;
   vm.showInvoices = false;
   vm.showWarehouses = false;
}

vm.showComponent = function(componentName)
{
   hideComponents();
   switch (componentName) {
      case "Regions":
         vm.showRegions = true;
         break;
      case "Accounts":
         vm.showAccounts = true;
         break;
      case "Orders":
         vm.showOrders = true;
         break;
      case "Invoices":
         vm.showInvoices = true;
         break;
      case "Warehouses":
         vm.showWarehouses = true;
         break;
      default:
   }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to achieve this functionality?

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
var setComponentVisibility = function (componentName = null)
{
   var bool = false;
   var map = {
       'Regions': vm.showRegions = bool,
       'Accounts': vm.showAccounts = bool,
       'Orders': vm.showOrders = bool,
       'Invoices': vm.showInvoices = bool,
       'Warehouses': vm.showWarehouses = bool
   }
   if (componentName != null)
   {
      // code to set bool to true only for that componentName in map
      // is this even possible?
      // if so, how?
   }
}
```

However, being new to AngularJS, I'm not sure the above is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to have custom object key by `['text'+variable]`.

```
vm.showComponent = function(componentName)
{
   hideComponents();
   vm['show' + componentName]=true;
}
```

Comment: Answers with just code and  without some explanation are not good answers. And as the code you have given is sloppy (no spaces between operators and missing a `;`)  I am down voting your answer.

Comment: @Blindman67 edited, but the code itself was self-explanation ,do you think adding that text helps user better understanding,rather than the looking the code?

Comment: The OP does not seam to be aware of bracket notation. An explanation of bracket notation (or a link) would improve the answer.

Comment: The addition of bracket notation information was helpful.  Much appreciated.